React Hook Form controlled component. Two inputs as one single value
I'm trying to create a combo component/input field that will consists of a dropdown list and simple text field.
I assume I need to use the useController option from react hook form but this is as far I can go.
I know for sure that I can pass two names to that component and get two values separately in order to merge them as one during submit but...
I want to get a single value out of those two fields if possible.
For example the select field has the options of countries phone prefixes and the input field will be free.
So if I get the value +44 for the select and the value 1234567890 I want to merge them as a single value. Meaning +441234567890.
I used the register and control from react-hook-form but I have no clue on how to merge those values as one.
Any help or examples unifying two input fields as one would be greatly appreciated.

are you using react-hook-form?

If you are using react-hook-form there is a concept watch. you can watch the changes happening to a field or fields.
const { register, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm();

  const watchFields = watch(["code", "phone"]);

Here is a working sample

Sounds promising.
So I'll pass both names (code, phone) to my child controlled component and in parent component (form) I can watch those two values and when I submit the form I'll use the values of those watched fields.
Thanks a lot!
I'll try it!

Sorry for my delayed response.
It did work. Thank you!
